Why is the question about remembering neural network closed?
ML. How to make a neural network remember the context and data?.
I want to figure out what went wrong: I asked a question about how to make a neural network remember, but they said that it was not about programming, why?

Is it a programming question?

Perhaps you could elaborate on what you feel is programming related in your question? Your question doesn't even have a programming language tagged, nor any tools that are specifically designed for programmers.

There is a separate network for AI questions: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Based on their tour I don't think what the OP posted would be on topic there either, @kmdreko .

"but they said that it was not about programming, why?" Because it isn't. Why do you believe it is?

@KarlKnechtel, Because I was interested in getting an answer on how to program a neural network to memorize information.

In which programming language do you want the answer? You don't specify the one in your question post. If you haven't choose the language, then your problem is not ready to be posted on Stack Overflow.

@Tsyvarev,  in UE/Unity

Okay, let's say your question was about programming. You've defined the language; now show us the Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@AugustoVasques, okay, but I don't quite understand how to make a minimal reproducible example when it comes to game engines and not a single script?

The point is, if you (or anyone) can't build a mcve, it's either because it's not a programming question, or because there are several questions to go through before you get an atomic programming question. Improve your post.

@AugustoVasques I'm not talking about OP's question but not all questions require an MRE, how-to questions are perfectly on-topic for the site (as long as they are reasonably scoped)

It's mostly the wrong place to ask. SO is more for implementation questions, not so much for design questions. I would say that deciding on a suitable architecture for a software is kind of programming related but not directly in scope for StackOverflow. Try another exchange ai or maybe software engineering or maybe even cross validated, but check on each before. And give details of what exactly you want. Give examples if possible.

If I have a question about the food at a restaurant, it doesn't become a question about cars, just because I want to drive in order to get there. To have a question about cars, I need to talk about the driving process, not the food.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, There are a couple of points that are generally quite strange and makes efforts are pointless: 1. Even if you imagine that the question will be opened, a reputation of -9 will repel and motivate you to lower the question further, like a snowball (minuses are not reset). 2. “Life” on other Stack Exchanges is several times less, since few people try to check every related Q&A; the majority believes that almost everything happens on SO

@KarlKnechtel, I didn't understand your analogy to this question

@NikolaiVorobiev ""Life” on other Stack Exchanges is several times less, since few people try to check every related Q&A; the majority believes that almost everything happens on SO" That's not true. There is lots of life elsewhere and SO doesn't want this question as you have experienced. I want to help you and my advice is, go to another stackexchange and add details to your question.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, Thank You! The only moment I said life is less, I already checked it, 3-4 question daily

Whatever "life" in other sites is low or high, does not change that your question is off-topic in Stack Overflow. Specially as you are asking about capabilities of neural networks, which is not a programming specific feature of them.

@Dr.Snoopy, Okey, I thought until now that it is close topics

Actually no, you might be surprised that there are researchers that do completely theoretical arguments about neural networks, without any implementation, and without any programming.

@Dr.Snoopy, Yes, there are such people, but they are definitely not the majority.

@Dr.Snoopy, is the question titled "NEAT implementation for RNN" compliant with SO standards?

Impossible to say from just a question title...

@Dr.Snoopy, Ok, description is: There is an algorithm for changing topologies (NEAT), but it is only for MLP, and in my project there is more than one neural network at a time, which also needs to remember the past. But I did not find NEAT for RNN (LSTM, GRU), I did not choose a transformer, because several simultaneously running transformers (for which there is also no NEAT) create a much greater load.

There is no question there, and its based on the wrong premises (NEAT is generic and not for specific architectures), also note that comments here are not meant as chat but to clarify your original question.

@NikolaiVorobiev - If you don’t improve the question it can never be upvoted by those user who issued a downvote nor can the question be reopened

It is impossible to judge from a title, but it does kind of read like you are asking people to write a novel for you. That would fall into the territory of "too broad", too large a scope. Huge requirements need to be split up into smaller problems. If you can't do that... Stack Overflow is not on the menu.

@Gimby, One question: for some reason my reputation returned back to 49, but at the same time I cannot ask questions, what happened?

@Gimby, I am accidentally found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237626/how-to-evolve-lstm-model-using-neat-neural-evolution-of-augmenting-topologies. Why it did not downvoted or closed, it has the same problems?
